# Python's way to store a default value if expression failed

Tags: python, shortcut

What is the python analog of perl's `//` operator?

In perl, one can do something like :

```
$pos = $some_list[0] // 1
```

How do you accomplish the same in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python there *is no `undefined`*; instead, you'd get an exception if you tried to access an non-existent index in a list. As such, you can use exception handling instead:

```
try:
    pos = some_list[0]
except IndexError:
    pos = 1
```

For the first element of a sequence, you could explicitly test the sequence as a boolean (a python container is 'falsey' when empty):

```
post = some_list[0] if some_list else 1
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using exceptions?

```
try:
    pos = some_list[0]
except (NameError, IndexError):
    pos = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The best practice for this in python is to handle exceptions explicitly with a try, except clause. One example presented here to help you visuallize

```
my_list = []
try:
    item = my_list[1]
except IndexError:
    item = 1
```

Here the code executes and an exception is raised because the index "1" is out of bounds. We then go on to handle that exception and set `item=1` allowing the program to continue running. The reason for this explicit handling of exceptions is so we as programmers see exactly what is causing our problems. Take this for example:

```
my_list = [0]
try:
    item = 1/my_list[0]
except IndexError:
    item = 1
```

This will raise a zero division error (halting execution) and let us know that we need to handle some other exception explicitly beyond the original exception we expected, the IndexError. We might then do something like this to deal with that situation:

```
my_list = [0]
try:
    item = 1/my_list[0]
except IndexError:
    item = 1
except ZeroDivisionError:
    item = 99999
```

try-except blocks also have a few other notable features we can exploit:

```
try:
    # code which might raise error
    pass
except IndexError as err:
    # handling an index error and storing the traceback in err
    pass
except ZeroDivisionError:
    #handling some other error:
    pass
else:
    # code we would like to execute if the try block succeeds without any errors
    pass
finally:
    # code we will execute regardless of what occurs in the entire 
    # try,except,else block listed above (i.e we can ensure a file is closed)
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to try/catch answers above for dictionaries is the default argument on `.get()`:

```
param_value = my_dictionary.get(param_key, default_value)
```

Comment: Provided the OP has a dictionary, and not a list.

Comment: hence my caveat "for dictionaries"

Comment: But mappings in Perl use `{...}` instead.